# JPA : How to update users' deposit correctly?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions

Our `User` class is defined as below :

```
public User{
    // 账户余额 (Account Balance)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public BigDecimal deposit = new BigDecimal(0);
}
```

Now we need to update user's deposit in different transactions, but here's where we meet a problem. For example :

1. Transaction A read `deposit = 1000` from database.
2. Transaction B read `deposit = 1000` from database.
3. Transaction B takes 200 from user's `deposit`, and modifies `deposit` to 800.
4. Transaction A takes 500 from user's `deposit`, and modifies `deposit` to 500.
5. Transaction B write 800 back.
6. Transaction A write 500 back.

In this case, our user actually cost 700 `deposit` and should only have 300 left. but the last transaction override it to a wrong number.

How do we correct this ?

My first idea is to add a `@Transient` field represent the data we read from database, when we need to update `User`, the `deposit` in database should be the same with the `@transient` field we assigned before. But how to mapping `@transient` to the exist database column(that means when we load `User`, the `@transient` field should be auto filled) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hitting a well known problem.

The simplest way to solve it is to use some kind of locking, either pessimistic locking on the database or optimistic locking in the application.

Comment: My solution is a kind of `optimistic` lock, but I don't know how to map `deposit` database column to the `@Transient` field.

Comment: Search for the @Version annotation, that implements optimistic locking for jpa.